# How to insert current time and future time into MySQL database using JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat7

I am having a really hard time inserting a proper datetime into MySQL database. The database is set up as:

aucID, int(11) AI

minprice, float

startprice, float

startdatetime, datetime

enddatetime, datetime

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<% 



   try{
        String itemid = request.getParameter("itemid");   
        String startprice = request.getParameter("startprice");
        String minprice = request.getParameter("minprice");
        String startdate = request.getParameter("current");
        String enddate = request.getParameter("length");

        System.out.println(itemid);

        System.out.println(startprice);
        System.out.println(minprice);
        System.out.println(startdate);
        System.out.println(enddate);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxx","xxx", "xxx");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO auctions (minprice, startprice, startdatetime, enddatetime, itemid) VALUES ('" + minprice + "','" + startprice + "','" + itemid + "','" + ADD CURRENT DATE + "','" + ADD FUTURE DATE + "')");
        con.close();

        String URL = "addauction.jsp";
        response.sendRedirect(URL); 

    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    %>
```

I am building a basic auction site. I need to be able to set the time of created auction and set a future date when the auction ends.

If you would be able to show me how to compare the time too that would be super helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For `startdatetime` you could use `ON UPDATE` trigger. Also `DATETIME` has an optional argument `fsp` which is a number of fractional digits of a second. Why just you invoke MySql command line and type _\help datetime_?

Comment: If you can alter your database, please read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using prepared statements, you can bind timestamp arguments using the `java.sql.Timestamp` type.

```
String sql = "insert into tbl (col1, col2, col3) values (?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setTimestamp(3, Timestamp.valueOf(new LocalDateTime().now()));
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

MySQL also accepts `DATETIME` values as strings in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. You can generate a time string in this format using `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

// 2018-08-03 03:50:17
LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);

// 2018-09-03 03:50:17
LocalDateTime.now().plusMonths(1).format(formatter);
```

Now all you have to do is create the right `LocalDateTime` for your form parameters (`startdate` and `enddate`), and then either bind a `Timestamp` argument or concatenate a formatted `DATETIME` string.

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp`, `java.time.LocalDateTime`,  `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Will try now. Few minutes.

Comment: So using prepared statement, `setTimestap(3, xz)` what does the 3 do? Does it put it into the third slot?

Comment: That's the parameter index (the first parameter (?) is 1, the second is 2, etc.)

Comment: Getting error for `stmt.setTimestamp(3,Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime().now()));` where LocalDateTime is undefined for the type

Comment: `(new LocalDateTime()).now()`

Comment: Getting another error.. Static method `now()` should be defined static.. Nevermind hold on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177372/discussion-between-sgerbhctim-and-jspcal).

Comment: How do I avoid using ??? ,, getting error `No value specified for parameter 1` but that is an autoincrementing PK

Comment: You can specify the columns to assign with `insert into tbl (col1, col2, col3) values (?, ?, ?)`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your String "startdate" to a date object. Then add a future date, or manipulate the date as you see fit.

```
//Convert string to date.  
String string = "January 2, 2010";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss");
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date); // Sat Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT 2010

//Plus future day.
DateTime dtOrg = new DateTime(date);
DateTime dtPlusOne = dtOrg.plusDays(1);
```

Comment: Any packages to include? Getting `DateFormat cannot be resolved`

Comment: Try use only SimpleDateFormat like `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss");`

Comment: I don't think this answer satisfy the request. E.g. why do you need to convert `datetime` to `date`? What if OP wants the exactly time when something is inserted into the DB?

Comment: Still getting error `SimpleDateFormat` cannot be resolved as type.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me is to configure the TimeStamp field in the Table to have the default Now(), so every time you add something in the DB and don't provide that field, it will be automatically filled for you.